# ArcGIS Extract by Attributes Error: "A column was specific that does not exist."

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have a single band DEM raster. I am attempting to use the tool "Extract by Attributes" but am getting the error:

```
"A column was specified that does not exist"
```

My raster is a single band raster. My understanding is that thus the only column name is "VALUE". I am trying to extract a raster where the value is between a certain range. To ensure I have entered the SQL query correctly I have used the SQL Query creator which is built into the "Extract by Attributes" tool. Here is an example of my inputs with the query shown:

[[image: Inputs to Extract by Attributes tool[1]]

What is the error in my approach?

Comment: Are you sure `BETWEEN` is supported? Have you tried something simpler, like `VALUE=204`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried this and it worked. Indeed, "BETWEEN" is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

The function "BETWEEN" is not supported. The term "VALUE" is the correct name for a single band raster of this type. As such changing the formula to the below fixes the problem and produces the correct result:

```
"VALUE >= 204 AND VALUE <= 404"
```